# Laptop logging out of window manager a few minutes after boot up and login

Tags: linux, reboot, window-manager, gdm

I have a troubling issue. I log into **Linux Mint 9** (fully up-to-date) on my Samsung Q320 laptop with power connected and after a few minutes it seems like the entire X session dies, I am logged out, all processes are killed and I am presented with the normal GDM login screen. When I first installed Linux Mint, this never happened.

I have the **NVidia** closed-source driver installed and when the system logs me out, it immediately restarts X loading the NVidia driver which flashes the logo on screen. This all happens instantaneously, so it is not a reboot of the machine, just a restart of the display manager it seems.

There does not seem to be any cause for this. **I have disabled all screen saver and power management settings** that may lead my system to auto-logout of Gnome.

Does anyone have any advice for how I might do about diagnosing the cause of this behaviour. The system log doesn't indicate anything unusual happening. Confused about where to to take it from here bar and fresh install of the OS. Perhaps there are some X11 logs I should be checking.

**Update:**

Moved to Ubuntu 10.10 and its recommended NVidia driver and have not experienced this problem since.

Comment: You should definitely look for some X11 logs. On Debian/Ubuntu, they're kept in `/var/log/gdm/:0.log`. If you can't find the logs, try logging in from the text console (press `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, enter your name and password, and start X with the commad `startx -- :1`). When the session dies, you'll be returned to a prompt with the last few lines of error messages (if any) still visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout everything in /var/log and see if there is anything suspicious.